# windows - How to stop cron job of .bat file?

Tags: php, windows, batch-file, cron, xampp

i have used it . but now it is pouping up again and  again how to stop it

To create the batch file

Open Notepad.
Paste the line "C:\xampp\php\php.exe C:\wamp\www\index.php"
Click "File" -> "Save As"
Ensure "Save as type:" is set to "All Files"
Save the file as "cron.bat" to your C drive
To schedule the batch file to run

Open Command Prompt
Paste the following "schtasks /create /sc minute /mo 1 /tn "PHP Cron Job" /tr C:\cron.bat"
Press Enter

Comment: For any Windows console command you can always read the help for the command by opening a cmd prompt and typing the command name followed by a /?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
schtasks /Delete
```

More could be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb736357(v=vs.85).aspx)

What happened is you created a scheduled task to run each minute. So it is doing what you said it to do. If you want to remove it, use above command.